# VIM is not working as expected with relative path address of a file

Tags: vim, terminal, gnome-terminal

Let's say I am in my directory `~/bin` and I want to open a file which is in `~/mySetting/commands.txt`. 
So, from the terminal when I enter `vim ../mySetting/commands.txt`, vim opens it as a new directory. But when I enter the full path like `vim ~/mySetting/commands.txt`, It opens it as expected.
Does VIM not work with relative path?? 
Or

Comment: your problem cannot be reproduced here. If you opened `vim ../foo/bar.txt`, and save, where vim is gonna write the new file?

Comment: It's possible if `~/bin` is a symlink to somewhere deeper in the hierarchy. For example, if `~/bin` is a symlink to `~/.local/share/bin` then `../mySetting/commands.txt` would be `~/.local/share/mySetting/commands.txt`. To test: `ls -l ~/bin` and `cd ~/bin && ls -l ../mySetting/commands.txt`

Comment: @phd Thanks, It was actually a symlink created by me few days ago. Would you like to post your comment as answer?? I will accept it as a answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible if `~/bin` is a symlink to somewhere deeper in the hierarchy. For example, if `~/bin` is a symlink to `~/.local/share/bin` then `../mySetting/commands.txt` would be `~/.local/share/mySetting/commands.txt`.

To test: `ls -l ~/bin` and `cd ~/bin && pwd -P && ls -l ../mySetting/commands.txt`